# How to deal with media queries/non-inline styling with Emails.

Tags: html, css, email, styles, media-queries

I just got done building/updating 3 emails. I upload the html from one of the email to MailChimp to send a test email to our Gmail test account. None of the styling I applied shows up. I'm not an html expert, but it's clear that there are quite a few media queries already in the html file, and for some reason these work - mines don't. They work fine when I open the html file in the browser, but not when I send it to email accounts. I understand that I will have to write inline styles for things like color, padding, font-size, etc, but how do I write inline styles for media queries?

Thanks for any help with this dilemma I'm having...

Answer (score 1):

Making emails responsive and adding CSS is extremely time consuming. I recommend using a responsive email framework like Foundation for Emails https://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html or MJML Email foundations https://mjml.io/. These frameworks, allow you to create your own css which is then added as inline styles to your emails. You can then copy and paste the HTML to mailchimp and send.  Each of these frameworks has a slight learning curve, but they make building and updating email templates a lot easier.